# sql for subtracting two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im having issues making this query work. Can anyone help.
I have two set of queries that I want to merge together.

the first one is

```
SELECT 'Total Calls Hitting the Office' as "Report"
    ,Call_date as "Date"
    ,SUM([Calls) as "Total"
    ,'Calls' as "Units"
FROM Call
GROUP BY Call_date
```

and this query is generated using 2 tables.

```
 select 'Total Calls Coming through the Call Centre' as "Report"
  ,Interval_Start_date as "Date"
  ,sum(MyCS.Incoming + MyCA.Abandoned)/4 as "Total"
  , 'Calls' as " Units"
    From call_callsummary as MyCS
   left join Call_abandonedcalls as MyCA
   on MyCS.Interval_Start_date = MyCA.CallAbandoned_date
   where MyCS.Category <> 'Application
```

My third query is meant to subtract the second query TOTAL from the first QUERY TOTAL...

I have tried using the query below merging the 3 tables together but I am getting results which is like 10 times more than the desired result should be.

```
select 'Total Calls Dealt Within the office' as "Report"
  ,Call_date as "Date"
  ,sum(MyC.[Calls]) - Sum(MyCS.Incoming + MyCA.Abandoned)/4 as "Total"
  ,'Calls' as " Units"
    FROM Call as MyC inner join call_callsummary as MyCS
    on MyCS.Interval_Start_date = MyC.Call_date
   inner join Call_abandonedcalls as MyCA
   on MyCS.Interval_Start_date = MyCA.CallAbandoned_date  
   where MyCS.Category <> 'Application'
   group by Call_date
```

Comment: use variables , assign values to those variable and then try to subtract it

Comment: use a NOT IN structure to remove the unwanted rows.

Comment: You are missing a `GROUP BY` in the second query. Do you want the result per date?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag due to the usage of non-standard `[..]` "quotes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH TotalCallsHittingTheOffice AS (
    SELECT Call_date as "Date"
          ,SUM(Calls) as "Total"
    FROM Call
    GROUP BY Call_date
)
,TotalCallsComingThroughTheCallCentre AS (
    SELECT Interval_Start_date as "Date"
           SUM(MyCS.Incoming + MyCA.Abandoned)/4 as "Total"
    FROM   call_callsummary as MyCS
           LEFT JOIN Call_abandonedcalls as MyCA
               ON Call_abandonedcalls.CallAbandoned_date = call_callsummary.Interval_Start_date = 
    WHERE  call_callsummary.Category <> 'Application'
    GROUP BY Interval_Start_date
)
SELECT 'Total Calls Dealt Within the office' AS "Report"
      ,TotalCallsHittingTheOffice."Date" AS "Date"
      ,SUM(TotalCallsHittingTheOffice."Total" - COALESCE(TotalCallsComingThroughTheCallCentre."Total", 0))
      ,'Calls' AS " Units"
FROM TotalCallsHittingTheOffice
     LEFT JOIN TotalCallsComingThroughTheCallCentre
        ON TotalCallsHittingTheOffice."Date" = TotalCallsComingThroughTheCallCentre."Date"
GROUP BY TotalCallsHittingTheOffice."Date"
```

Comment: Please one last thing..My queries are a union join and with the query starting as a WITH..the union join doesn't like it. How do I rewrite it to make the union accept it.

Comment: What is a union join? Do you mean `UNION ALL`? Just move the WITH clauses to the top. Before the first select in the union

Answer (score 1):

Most databases have `minus` or `except` to subtract two queries. This sample works for example on Oracle (using `minus`):

```
SELECT Call_date as "Date"
,      SUM([Calls) as "Total"
,      'Calls' as "Units"
FROM   Call
GROUP
BY     Call_date
except
select Interval_Start_date as "Date"
,      sum(MyCS.Incoming + MyCA.Abandoned)/4 as "Total"
,      'Calls' as " Units"
From   call_callsummary as MyCS
left
join   Call_abandonedcalls as MyCA
on     MyCS.Interval_Start_date = MyCA.CallAbandoned_date
where  MyCS.Category <> 'Application
```

If you want to subtract the *values* instead of the rows, use the query below. It joins the rows on `date` and subtracts their values:

```
select x.date
,      x.total - y.total
,      x.units - y.units
from   ( SELECT Call_date as "Date"
         ,      SUM([Calls) as "Total"
         ,      'Calls' as "Units"
         FROM   Call
         GROUP
         BY     Call_date
       ) x
  join ( select Interval_Start_date as "Date"
         ,      sum(MyCS.Incoming + MyCA.Abandoned)/4 as "Total"
         ,      'Calls' as " Units"
         From   call_callsummary as MyCS
         left
         join   Call_abandonedcalls as MyCA
         on     MyCS.Interval_Start_date = MyCA.CallAbandoned_date
         where  MyCS.Category <> 'Application
       ) y
  on   x.date = y.date
```

Comment: I guess he want to subtract `Total` in the second query from `Total` in first query, not remove rows?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to omit the first selected item, the one named "Report"?  When I've used MINUS this column would have prevented the matching of any rows in the first and second queries.

Comment: Just to add to this: in this case (question is tagged `SQL Server`) the keyword is `EXCEPT` which works exactly as you posted it for `MINUS` in Oracle

Comment: tHANKS, I just want to subtract the two totals.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: That one was added later. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With TotalCallsFromCallCentre 
As
(
 select 'Total Calls Coming through the Call Centre' as "Report"
  ,Interval_Start_date as "Date"
  ,sum(MyCS.Incoming + MyCA.Abandoned)/4 as "Total"
  , 'Calls' as " Units"
    From call_callsummary as MyCS
   left join Call_abandonedcalls as MyCA
   on MyCS.Interval_Start_date = MyCA.CallAbandoned_date
   where MyCS.Category <> 'Application'
)
select 'Total Calls Dealt Within the office' as "Report"
  ,Call_date as "Date"
  ,Sum(Total - Call.[Calls])
  ,'Calls' as " Units"
  From Call inner join TotalCallsFromCallCentre on Call.Call_Date = TotalCallsFromCallCentre.Date
Group by Call_Date
```

Though I could not try this in SQL Server, but it should work.

Comment: I have about 5 queries using union all to join them..the last 2 queries worked independently but it wont work when i try to union all them with the rest of my queries..how do I rewrite this please

Comment: Share your all queries and link between these queries... Will surely help you.

Comment: query 1: SELECT 'Total Calls Hitting the IVR' as "Report"
  ,[Call_date] as "Date"
  ,SUM([Calls]) as "Total"
  ,'Calls' as "Units"
  FROM [WLA].[dbo].[MyCall]
  GROUP BY [Call_date]
  
  union all
  
 query 2: the query you help me rewite



I need query 1&2 to union all together

Comment: What if you write my query as query 1 and do union all with your query `My Query Union All SELECT 'Total Calls Hitting the IVR' as "Report" ,[Call_date] as "Date" ,SUM([Calls]) as "Total" ,'Calls' as "Units" FROM [WLA].[dbo].[MyCall] GROUP BY [Call_date]`

Comment: There is a query at the top. My boss wants it like for like....sorry If its a pain

Comment: In that case, CTE can't be used. You can take reference from  Patrick Hofman second query. That can be used in union clause. That too is correct.